# Equidistant sampling over opencv contour

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, sampling

I'm trying to get an equidistant sample from an OpenCV contour in order to calculate the Fourier descriptor of this shape.

I have currently extracted the contours correctly using `cv.findContours()`, but the resulting `numpy` array has points with alternating distances between them. What I'm trying to do is generate a sample over this contour which has an equal distance between all points.

What I've tried now is tracking the original contour and drawing points at the correct distance in the direction of the closest next point of the original contour.

The problem with this approach is that it's near impossible to get the correct distance at the end of the shape.

Is there some other way of doing this? I feel like there should be something like `numpy.linspace` that works for entire shapes instead of just 2 points, but I haven't been able to find something alike.

I hope everything is clear, thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use a findContour parameter to extract every contour pixel without subsampling. From there you could move along the contour and count pixel-to-pixel distance along the contour to get the total contour circumference and divide it by your wanted number of points and afterwards, in a second run select such points (by again measuring distance along the contour, pixel by pixel.

Comment: @Micka Isn't the sum of "pixel-to-pixel distances" exactly what [`arcLength`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga8d26483c636be6b35c3ec6335798a47c) returns?

Comment: @HansHirse probably you are right, that will likely make things easier!